# Exporting data to Google Spreadsheet from Google App Engine (Java version)

Tags: google-app-engine, google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

I am getting no where now. When I Google around to find a sample of "Exporting data to Google Spreadsheet from Google App Engine", I see a lot of Google Conversion API, Google Conversion API, Google Spreadsheet API and Google Docs API tutorials. But then they all deprecated from Google when I check at the Google site??? So, what is the most updated right now so I can make use of it?

=====

Okay now I use the Google Drive SDK via OAuth2 to create text file. But I have problem with this:

this is the error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>     at
>   java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3004)
>   at
>   java.net.URI.(URI.java:577)
>      at
>   com.google.api.client.http.GenericUrl.(GenericUrl.java:100)
>      at
>   com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.upload(MediaHttpUploader.java:269)
>     at
>   com.google.api.services.drive.Drive$Files$Insert.executeUnparsed(Drive.java:309)
>     at
>   com.google.api.services.drive.Drive$Files$Insert.execute(Drive.java:331)
>     **at
>   com.company.dashboard.service.DriveService.initDoc(DriveService.java:84)**

this is the code:

```
private GoogleCredential buildGoogleCredential(Credential credential) {
    try {
        logger.warning(oauth2Service.getClientCredential().toString());
        GoogleCredential googleCredential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                                                .setClientSecrets(oauth2Service.getClientCredential())
                                                .setTransport(new NetHttpTransport())
                                                .setJsonFactory(new JacksonFactory()).build();

        googleCredential.setAccessToken(credential.getAccessToken());
        googleCredential.setRefreshToken(credential.getRefreshToken());

        return googleCredential;

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}

private Drive buildService(GoogleCredential credential) {

    return new Drive.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(), new JacksonFactory(), credential).build();
}

public void initDoc(HttpServletRequest req) 
        throws Exception {
    User user = UserServiceFactory.getUserService().getCurrentUser();

    Credential credential = oauth2Service.getStoredCredential(
            user.getUserId(), 
            (CredentialStore)req.getSession().getServletContext().getAttribute(OAuth2Constant.GOOG_CREDENTIAL_STORE));

    if (credential != null) {
        logger.warning("Using access token: " + credential.getAccessToken());

        try {
            GoogleCredential googleCredential = buildGoogleCredential(credential);

            Drive service = buildService(googleCredential);

            if (service == null) {
                logger.warning("very bad!");
            }

            File body = new File();
            body.setTitle("My document");
            body.setDescription("A test document");
            body.setMimeType("text/plain");

            java.io.File fileContent = new java.io.File("document.txt");
            FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("text/plain", fileContent);

            service.files().insert(body, mediaContent).execute();
            //File file = service.files().insert(body, mediaContent).execute();
            //System.out.println("File ID: " + file.getId());

        } catch (HttpResponseException e) {
          if (e.getStatusCode() == 401) {
              logger.warning(e.getMessage());
            // Credentials have been revoked.
            // TODO: Redirect the user to the authorization URL.
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
          }
        } catch (IOException e) {
          System.out.println("An error occurred: " + e);
        }
    }
```

oauth2Service.getClientCredential() returns (xxx = client id and client secret code, not shown in here)

> {"web":{"client_id":"xxx.apps.googleusercontent.com","client_secret":"xxx"}}

This is my scope:

```
final static List<String> SCOPES = Arrays.asList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile", 
                                                 "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
                                                 "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
                                                 "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/docs",
                                                 "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file");
final static String AUTH_RESOURCE_LOC = "/client_secrets.json";
final static String OATH_CALLBACK = "http://localhost:8888/oauth2callback";
```

This line

> service.files().insert(body, mediaContent).execute();

throws NullPointerException. Any idea what had gone wrong???

P/S: Credential = com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential. I have my OAuth2 everything works good. I can retrieve user info without problem but not the Drive API. service is not null as you see I put it the log as "very bad" and it is not shown. No 401 exception is thrown means my Oauth2 is good with the scopes.

=======

### DARN!!!! Finally solved the issue!!! My code was totally correct! Just I enabled the wrong API! It should be Drive API instead of Drive SDK API :/

Comment: Exporting data from where? The datastore?

Comment: I want to generate Spreadsheet from GAE for reporting. I want this solution.

Comment: @DanHolevoet, to Google Drive :)

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a csv file from GAE and upload it using the Drive API with `?convert=true` to have it automatically converted to a Google spreadsheet:

https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert

Comment: FileWriter is not support in GAE @@"

Comment: HAHA! I have done it :) with this magic => "service.files().insert(file, ByteArrayContent.fromString(clientFile.mimeType, clientFile.content)).setConvert(true).execute();"