# How do I access a Google Spreadsheet from App Engine using a Service Account?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

I have an application on Google App Engine (hosted on appspot.com) which is going to be used by a few users to grab some stuff off the internet, save it in the Datastore and then write it to a Google Spreadsheet. I'm looking to use a Service Account to access the spreadsheet but I run into a 400 OK { "error" : "invalid_grant" } problem when I try to do anything, regardless of whether I try to create a file using the Drive API or access an existing file using Spreadsheets API.

I've turned on both Drive API and Drive SDK in the APIs Console and generated a P12 key. This is my method for building a `GoogleCredential`:

```java
private GoogleCredential getGoogleCredential() throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
    .setTransport(TRANSPORT)
    .setJsonFactory(FACTORY)
    .setServiceAccountId("1511XXX90247.apps.googleusercontent.com")
    .setServiceAccountScopes(scopes)
    .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(
            new File("05a605b0fXXXd2a6be864be15d81a2bd629d3bd6-privatekey.p12"))
    .setServiceAccountUser("XXX@gmail.com") // My personal e-mail address which I used to create the project
    .build();
    return credential;
}
```

The ServiceAccountID comes from the APIs Console. I've tried using `1511XXX90247@developer.gserviceaccount.com` as my ServiceAccountUser as well as `myappname@appspot.gserviceaccount.com`. The scopes I'm using are as follows:

```
https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds
https://docs.google.com/feeds
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file
```

Here is the code that fails when I try to use Spreadsheets API:

```java
        SpreadsheetService service = new SpreadsheetService("name of my app");
        service.setOAuth2Credentials(getGoogleCredential());
        FeedURLFactory factory = FeedURLFactory.getDefault();
        SpreadsheetQuery query = new SpreadsheetQuery(factory.getSpreadsheetsFeedUrl());
        query.setTitleQuery("test");
        SpreadsheetFeed feed = service.query(query, SpreadsheetFeed.class);
```

The code fails when the service tries execute the query.

Here's the Drive code I tried that also fails:

```java
        Drive drive = new Drive.Builder(TRANSPORT, FACTORY,
                 getGoogleCredential()).build();
        com.google.api.services.drive.model.File file = new com.google.api.services.drive.model.File();
        file.setTitle("test");       
        file.setMimeType("application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet");
        drive.files().insert(file).execute(); // This is where the code fails
```

No matter what I try, I always seem to end up with the same ìnvalid grant` error. Here's a partial stacktrace:

```java
com.google.gdata.util.AuthenticationException: Failed to refresh access token: 400 OK { "error" : "invalid_grant" } 
at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleAuthTokenFactory$OAuth2Token.refreshToken(GoogleAuthTokenFactory.java:260) 
at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleAuthTokenFactory.handleSessionExpiredException(GoogleAuthTokenFactory.java:702) 
at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService.handleSessionExpiredException(GoogleService.java:738)    at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService.getFeed(GoogleService.java:680) 
at com.google.gdata.client.Service.query(Service.java:1237) 
at com.google.gdata.client.Service.query(Service.java:1178) 
at spam.gwt.scraper.server.spreadsheets.APIConnector.doGet(APIConnector.java:66)
```

I've tried to look for answers everywhere, including but not limited to the [Google Developers Spreadsheets Guide](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/), this [Service Account-related Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13229294/how-do-i-create-a-google-spreadsheet-with-a-service-account-and-share-to-other-g) and this [Google App Engine-specific Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13597074/exporting-data-to-google-spreadsheet-from-google-app-engine-java-version). What with the developments (eg. Docs -> Drive) it's hard to find up-to-date info, never mind info that pertains specifically to GAE.

Comment: It would appear I've solved the problem myself. I used `1511XXX90247@developer.gserviceaccount.com` as my ServiceAccountID and removed the ServiceAccountUser entirely.

Comment: please post your answer so this question can be closed

Answer (score 2):

I use the builtin Service Account of the App Engine application rather than creating my own; this way the private key is save (not stored locally, only on app engine).

For Drive:

```
    protected Drive createDriveService() throws BookingSheetException {

      HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
      JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
      GoogleClientRequestInitializer keyInitializer =
              new CommonGoogleClientRequestInitializer(API_KEY);
      AppIdentityCredential credential =
              new AppIdentityCredential.Builder(Arrays.asList(DriveScopes.DRIVE)).build();
      Drive service = new Drive.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, null)
          .setHttpRequestInitializer(credential)
          .setGoogleClientRequestInitializer(keyInitializer)
          .setApplicationName(appname).build();
      return service;
}
```

For Spreadsheet:

```
private Credential creds;
/**
 * Keep the expiration time of the access token to renew it before expiry
 */
private Calendar expirationTime = Calendar.getInstance();
protected void initCredentials() {
    List<String> scopes = Arrays.asList("https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds");
    AppIdentityService appIdentity = AppIdentityServiceFactory.getAppIdentityService();
    AppIdentityService.GetAccessTokenResult accessToken = appIdentity.getAccessToken(scopes);
    expirationTime.setTime(accessToken.getExpirationTime());
    expirationTime.add(Calendar.MINUTE,-REFRESH_MINUTES); //refresh some time before expiry
    creds = new Credential(BearerToken.authorizationHeaderAccessMethod());
    creds.setAccessToken(accessToken.getAccessToken());
}

public SpreadsheetUtil(String appname) {
    myService = new SpreadsheetService(appname);
    myService.setOAuth2Credentials(cred);
}
```

Make sure to `creds.refreshToken()` or reinitialize when they expire.